# Ordenar uma lista de objetos por uma lista de string

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

Gostaria de na função *GetAll* já trouxesse a lista de posts em ordem de acordo com a lista de *IDs* passados pelo parâmetro *module.Higlights*

```
List<Post> posts = new List<Post>();
var posts = PostService.GetAll(module.Highlights).ToList();
var postsAux = posts;
posts.Clear();
foreach (var item in module.Highlights){    
  var post = postAux.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == item);
  if(post != null)
     posts.Add(post);    
}
```

O sistema utiliza o *IMongoCollection*:

```
public IEnumerable<Post> GetAll<Post>(IEnumerable<string> ids)
{
  if (ids == null)
    return new List<Post>();

  var collection = Db.GetCollection<Post>(typeof(Post).Name);

  var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.In("Id", ids);

  return collection.Find(filter).ToList();
}
```

Já tentei o seguinte código sem êxito:

```
var query = from i in ids 
        join o in collection..AsQueryable()
        on i equals o.Id
        select o;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos revisar seu código, pois ele pode estar criando problemas fora do escopo da pergunta.

```
// Linha é irrelevante. A variavel `posts` será sobrescrita na proxima linha
// Ela deve ser removida
// List<Post> posts = new List<Post>();  // REMOVER
var posts = PostService.GetAll(module.Highlights).ToList();

// Objetos complexos são atribuidos por referência, sendo assim,
// `postAux` e `posts` são EXATAMENTE O MESMO OBJETO, são a mesma lista
// O que mexer em um, mexe no outro.
var postsAux = posts;
// Aqui limpou as duas listas, `posts` e `postAux`
posts.Clear();

// Esse esquema é reordenar lista é ruim, pois causa MEMORY LEAK
// Vc está duplicando as listas, o que é desnecessário,
// Aumentando processamento e consumo de memória
foreach (var item in module.Highlights){    
  var post = postAux.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == item);
  if(post != null)
     posts.Add(post);    
}
```

Segue como fazer a ordenação, evitando *memory leak*.

```
    // Faz a consulta normalmente
    var posts = _postService.Find(module_Highlights).ToList();

    // Reordena de acordo com os ids usados na pesquisa
    for (var i = module_Highlights.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var id = module_Highlights[i];
        var post = posts.Single(p=>p.Id.ToString().Equals(id));

        // usa a tecnica de pop and push para evitar memory leak
        posts.Remove(post);
        posts.Insert(0, post);
    }
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mW81jo).